# Bitshifting: Can someone explain what this code does?

Tags: php, go, bit-manipulation

So, I'm reading a book on Go (The Way to Go by Ivo Balbaert), and in it there is a code sample:

```
const hardEight = (1 << 100) >> 97
```

Since I don't have Go installed on this machine, I decided to translate it to PHP to see the results (via http://writecodeonline.com/php/ since I don't have PHP installed on this machine either):

```
echo (1 << 100) >> 97;
```

The result for the above is `8`....huh? So I wrote decided ok, lets write a for-loop from 0 to 100 and see the results:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
    echo $i . ": ";
    echo ($i << 100) >> 97;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

However, the results are:

```
0: 0
1: 8
2: 16
3: 24
4: 32
5: 40
6: 48
7: 56
8: 64
9: 72
10: 80
11: 88
12: 96
13: 104
14: 112
15: 120
16: 128
17: 136
18: 144
19: 152
20: 160
21: 168
22: 176
23: 184
24: 192
25: 200
26: 208
27: 216
28: 224
29: 232
30: 240
31: 248
32: 256
33: 264
34: 272
35: 280
36: 288
37: 296
38: 304
39: 312
40: 320
41: 328
42: 336
43: 344
44: 352
45: 360
46: 368
47: 376
48: 384
49: 392
50: 400
51: 408
52: 416
53: 424
54: 432
55: 440
56: 448
57: 456
58: 464
59: 472
60: 480
61: 488
62: 496
63: 504
64: 512
65: 520
66: 528
67: 536
68: 544
69: 552
70: 560
71: 568
72: 576
73: 584
74: 592
75: 600
76: 608
77: 616
78: 624
79: 632
80: 640
81: 648
82: 656
83: 664
84: 672
85: 680
86: 688
87: 696
88: 704
89: 712
90: 720
91: 728
92: 736
93: 744
94: 752
95: 760
96: 768
97: 776
98: 784
99: 792
100: 800
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on with the snippet? I know its bitshifting, but I don't understand bitshifting well enough to discern what is going on there. Thank you :)

Comment: it shifts the number by 100 bits to the left and then it shifts the result by 97 bits to the right, which is equivalent to just shifting by 3 bits to the left. Unless you have truncation when you shift. since you are shifting `1` you get `8` which is `2^3`.

Comment: You don't use your `$i` variable in your bit-shifting operation so the result is always the same.

Comment: `(1 << 100)` gives you binary `10000000...` with 99 zeros. Shifting back to the right, `>> 97` gives binary `100`, or decimal 8. `>> (100 - $i)` would produce the sequence `0, 2, 4, 8, 16...`

Comment: @jeroen good catch :) oops updating to reflect

Comment: You can also run Go code on the web via the go playground. http://play.golang.org .  Here is a link to similar bitshifting: http://play.golang.org/p/ZTorcy-qHs

Comment: @BrianDorsey Whoa totally forgot that Go has a playground xD today is just not my day haha thank you for that

Comment: I'd like to mention that bit shifting is all weird with constants, (1<<100)>>97 is 8 because the compiler evaluates it to (1<<3). If you change 100 and 97 to variables, you get 0 instead because it can't optimize it and thus truncates before it right shifts. And if you just do (1<<100) it will panic since the value overflows an int.

Comment: @Jsor doing `echo (1 << 100);` in php gives 68719476736? No panic. Is this right or just weirdness in PHP (it panics in Go and exits with int overflow)

Comment: I think it's weirdness with compile-time constant evaluation in Go. I'm making a post on golang-nuts right now about a possible compiler bug.

Comment: @Jsor: It's not weird; it's not a bug. Read [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: @jsanc623: In PHP, (1 << 100) = (1 << (100%PHP_INT_SIZE)). For PHP_INT_SIZE = 64,  (1 << 100) = (1 << (100%64)) = (1 << 36) = 68719476736.

Comment: @peterSO I missed the section in the spec that said "Constant expressions are always evaluated exactly; intermediate values and the constants themselves may require precision significantly larger than supported by any predeclared type in the language." I maintain it's weird, but you're right that it's allowed.

Comment: @Jsor: "Numeric constants represent values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow." [Constants](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants). [Constant expressions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 1 as an example(you loop through 0-100 but its the same principal for all)
Starting with what is inside the brackets:

```
(1 << 100)
```

will do a left shift on the number 1 by 100 places. this gives you 1 followed by 100 zeros. then, this really large number(known as a [googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)) gets shifted right by 97 which leaves you with:

```
1000
```

which is the binary representation of the decimal number 8. For the other numbers, they are converted to binary first(so 2 becomes 10, 3 becomes 11 etc..) and the calculation is applied.

Comment: @jsanc623 so you are showing the multiplication table for "8". $i<<3 is equivalent to $i*8 (and to `($i<<100)>>97`)

Comment: @zk82 multiplication table? Nooo - was just messing around with it after seeing it as an example in a Go book (The Way to Go) on the way to work.